# Twitter bootstrap 3 tooltips on all titles

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make tooltips appear on ALL title=""?

The only examples i find are defining specific #id in the javascript, but I have a table with 100+ entries. I'm not going to define 100 rows in the script at footer.

Comment: In a question like this, it helps to provide the code that *almost* works. I've done similar things on several versions of bootstrap, and I have to go look up how to do it for the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/125446

Just use a jQuery selector for anything with a title attribute...

```
$('[title]').tooltip();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), the following gets an ID, which you've already pointed out:

```
$('#example').tooltip(options)
```

The first part is just a jQuery selector, so the answer is something like:

```
$('[title]').tooltip(options)
```

or better

```
$('.mySemanticClass').tooltip(options)
```